# Find relevant websites from list of keywords

Tags: php, list

I have a list of 10,000+ keywords, specifically company names (ie: Best Buy, General Electric, etc.). I want to find relevant websites for all or most of these names, systematically.

How would I be able to go about this?

I'm thinking it'd be possible to copy from the list, paste to google, copy first website then paste on another list.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Google's Web Search Results API.

[Getting the basic hello world up.](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Search)

[PHP Access](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/#fonje_snippets_php)